# remove part of string in php dynamic integer

Tags: php, string, dynamic, str-replace

**SOLVED**

```
$str     = '<td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="24433">&times;</a></td>';
$str    .= '<td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="19216">&times;</a></td>';

$replace = '<td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="HOW CAN I REMOVE THE NUMBERS FROM ABOVE?">&times;</a></td>';

print_r (str_ireplace($replace, " ", $str));
```

[see result when deleting the  tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s2wz.png)

note that the $replace has no data-code="" value because it's dynamic in $str

how can i delete those numbers?

sorry for my bad English

Thanks people for you're help ^^
problem solved!

Comment: What you get as output?

Comment: it does nothing :p

Comment: you have a quotes mismatch for starters

Comment: If people post invalid code then you have to expect someone to pick up on it. Ok , so now you have corrected it - what is it you are trying to replace / delete exactly?

Comment: @YoeriPlovie how you add dynamic value into data-code=""?

Comment: i have that string into an database ... i want to echo it to the user but i want that <a> tag to be removed but as you can see the <a> tag has some dynamic value as data-code... so how can i delete that <a> tag?

Comment: @Gugan it comes from an cart SESSION that is saved into an DB

Comment: if you delete the `<a>` tag then you'll have an empty table cell

Comment: @RamRaider ok it works but my output isn't good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is to use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`

```
$str = '<td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="24433">&times;</a></td>
        <td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="19216">&times;</a></td>';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $str );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//td/a');

if( $col ){
    foreach( $col as $n )$n->parentNode->removeChild( $n );
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
$dom=$xp=null;
```

Comment: it deletes the `a` tags

Comment: Another solution would to have used `preg_replace` but I'm not so good with regex expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to `delete` the `td` which contains the value which come from `database` you should try this

suppose value from database is

```
$data = 19216;// from database
data-code="'.$data.'" // add this in $replace
```

then your code

```
$data = 19216;
$str     = '<td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="24433">&times;</a></td>';
$str    .= '<td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="19216">&times;</a></td>';
$replace = '<td class="text-right"> <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="'.$data.'">&times;</a></td>';// add $data here 
print_r (str_ireplace($replace, " ", $str));
```

This will remove entire `td` containing `data-code ="19216";`

Comment: this is not suitable for me, the $data is nested into ans href link and not saved separatly in db. thanks anyway